# Texture problems with min3d

Tags: textures, min3d

[image]

I'm working with min3d. Simply created a skymap and added the textures.

My problem is NOT that the textures not fitting like in the image below. (I only have to switch left and right)

BUT! Can you see the kink in the middle of each image?

When I rotate the skymap around the Y axis its like texture is on a sine curve.

It like the texture is moving in a sinecurve. This phenomenon occours is only for the skymap textures. Also if I add a rectangle and put a texture on it and than rotate or move the rectangle the texture is moving. It like it is projected.

I havn't had that problem before. I Also checked out min3d again and created a new eclipse project with the untouched min3d sources. Created a Skymap. Rendered it. Same effect.

Any Idea?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are not properly setting the sky box textures did you try this example: http://www.rozengain.com/blog/2010/10/21/min3d-for-android-sky-box-tutorial/

Comment: Answers should stand alone instead of containing nothing but a link.

Comment: what is very curious that this effect only apears on the emulator .. un my Smartphone the Skybox is displayed correctly.

Comment: Ya most of the time the emulator does not show real things, so always first test game type projects on real devices:)